# How to write a Query to remove duplicates and sort the table as per the frequency in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider I have a table like this:

```
Name        Age 
chethan      27
Sanjay       25      
Radha        54
Chethan      27
Radha        54
chethan      27
chethan      27
chethan      27
Radha        54
```

The output should be like

```
Name        Age 
chethan      27
Radha        54
Sanjay       25
```

That order is like this, Chethan on the top ,because it has occured the most number of times and Sanjay has appeared the least number.I should be able to write a SQL query for the same.

I tried using Distict but I am not getting the appropriate result

Comment: ``select distinct lower(name) as name, age from table  order by name``. `lower` ensures all the names are uniform.

Answer (score 1):

use  `group by` and order by `count(*)`

```
select name,age from tablename
group by name, age 
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: I think the table elements have to ordered by using Name column ,not the age because if you do it with age the first row should be Sanjay ...correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @GiritejaBille, actually it should be ordered by frequency, not name, not age !!

Comment: yeah ! Didn't see that part ..My bad

Comment: No the Name column should be ordered by the frequency of repetition of the names. Like  in the above example CHethan is repeated 5 times,Radha 3 times and Sanjay 1 times.So because Chethan has been repeated most number of times which is 5 he comes first,Radha the second most number of times ie,.3 so second and Sanjay only 1 so third

Comment: @Fahmi could you please help me by explaining what this actually does

Comment: @chethanv77777: this appears to do what you asked for. Did you test the query?

Comment: @chethanv77777, using the group by it will remove the duplicates and count(*) will give you the frequency by which you need to do the order by

Comment: @GMB Yes of course I tested the query but I had a slightly different situation. I had to basicaly run this command db.query('posts',distinct: true,columns: ['name','profileImagePath'],
      groupBy: 'name',orderBy: 'count(name) desc') in dart I had to do it.So I wanted to understand things

Comment: @Fahmi is Select distinct name,age from tablename Group by name,Order by Count(name) desc correct?

Comment: @chethanv77777, you don't need to add distinct as you are using group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the result turns out to be different.

You have one occurrence of 'Chethan' in addition to 4 occurrences of 'chethan' with a small 'c'.

```
WITH
input(Name,Age) AS (
          SELECT 'chethan',27
UNION ALL SELECT 'Sanjay' ,25
UNION ALL SELECT 'Radha'  ,54
UNION ALL SELECT 'Chethan',27  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Radha'  ,54
UNION ALL SELECT 'chethan',27
UNION ALL SELECT 'chethan',27
UNION ALL SELECT 'chethan',27
UNION ALL SELECT 'Radha'  ,54
)
SELECT
  name
, age
FROM input
GROUP BY 
  name
, age
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
-- out   name   | age 
-- out ---------+-----
-- out  chethan |  27
-- out  Radha   |  54
-- out  Sanjay  |  25
-- out  Chethan |  27
```

Comment: Oh I am very sorry,please ignore the case